# Converting new lines with quotes and comma in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert textarea text into a string I can put into the [postcodes.io](http://postcodes.io) checker API

Example of textarea:

```
TW7 8PX
TW14 8NU
W3 7JW
```

This then needs to convert to:

```
"TW7 8PX", "TW14 8NU", "W3 7JW"
```

Currently I am using a manual string:

```
$query = '"TW7 8PX", "TW14 8NU", "W3 7JW"';
$postcode = new Postcode();
$lookup = $postcode->bulkLookup(array($query));
```

I imagine it's achievable with preg_replace but I can't seem to find the combination I need.

Comment: Your `$query` line will cause a syntax error.  Please update your desired output to something valid so that the answerers can provide an accurate response.

Comment: @mickmackusa it didn't cause any issues as this is taken right off the test page I was using. However I have reached an answer. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Your question has actually resulted in wasting the time of several volunteers because they are trying to pack extra double-quotes into the string.  You have solved your own question as you understand it, not as the question states.  See the error: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d96d39c20b80af33d08d392ec3d428ee81d40da7  Please update your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa apologies that was never my intention

Comment: @mickmackusa I'll grant you that the $query line is invalid and misleading, but the initial information was clear enough that people were able to answer the question.  Furthermore, I don't feel that this question was about explode, nor answered by explode, even if explode is part of the solution.  Give the information provided, my solution illustrates that the proper formatting needed for a solution is inherent in the use of json_encode.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using only single line of code:

```
$result = '"' . implode('", "', explode("\n", $inputString)) . '"';
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are for matching a pattern, if your pattern is just a single character (newline in this case), they are overkill.

```
$query = '"'.str_replace("\n", '", "', $_POST['textarea']).'"';
```

Would do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like everyone here missed the obvious -- this is input for a REST api that wants json.

Here's the solution:

```
<?php

$input = <<< EOT
TW7 8PX
TW14 8NU
W3 7JW
EOT;

$output['postcodes'] = explode("\n", $input);
echo json_encode($output);
```

[Tested](https://3v4l.org/ko9pn)

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
<?php
$input = <<< EOT
TW7 8PX
TW14 8NU
W3 7JW
EOT;
foreach (explode("\n", $input) as $line) {
  $output[] = '"' . $line . '"';
}
var_dump(implode(', ', $output));
```

An alternative would be:

```
<?php
$input = <<< EOT
TW7 8PX
TW14 8NU
W3 7JW
EOT;
$output = '"' . implode('", "',explode("\n", $input)) . '"';
var_dump($output);
```

The obvious output is:

```
string(31) ""TW7 8PX", "TW14 8NU", "W3 7JW""
```

Comment: Too much code for simple task.

Comment: @tilz0R Indeed it appears bloated, certainly any programmer can implement something more crunchy. However consider the way the quote chars have to be added...

Comment: The *alternative* approach is the one. Or using `str_replace` is even much better and easier.

Comment: @tilz0R I oppose the wide spread habit to claim that there is only one, the "right" solution to a task. The first alternative is more flexible, for example it allows to simply add a call to `trim()` if desired...

Comment: It is not that hard, still single line and very efficient: `$output = '"' . implode('", "', array_map('trim', explode("\n", $input))) . '"';`

Comment: @tilz0R much harder to read. Keeping code in a single line is _not_ a virtue!

Comment: @tilz0R Actually, the first approach would technically be better if for example there were no values posted. The second option would result in `""` as output where the first would be an empty string. My answer has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$textAreaText = //whatever the field the value resides
$convertedText = '"' . implode('", "',explode("\n", $textAreaText)) . '"';
```

**Output**
"TW7 8PX", "TW14 8NU", "W3 7JW"

Tested on PhpFiddle

Comment: `'\n'` in single quotes is just a literal `\n`, not a newline. Plus, they are trying to remove the newlines.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Good catch... my oversight

Comment: OP already has multiline, OP wants single line.

Comment: @tilz0R - Got it... made the correction

Comment: They are also trying to quote each value.

Comment: And now it only quotes in between values.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Thank you... made the correction

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was very simple I was just looking at it the wrong way:

```
$query = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $_POST["postcodes"])); //Use Explode
$postcode = new Postcode();
$lookup = $postcode->bulkLookup($query); // Remove array()
```

Thank you for all your help

Comment: This is actually poor form, in you adding an answer to your own question, when many people provided you essentially this same answer, as well as all the techniques you utilized. Also your question omitted that apparently you used an api for the postal code service, but didn't provide information on what that api requires as input.  Also to @mickmackusa's point, your question has an invalid line of php code in it, when you do the assignment to $query.  You should remove or fix that line from your question.

Comment: From the link in your post I looked at the github for the various php libraries.    There are 4 listed:  https://github.com/ideal-postcodes/postcodes.io/  Not one that I looked at requires the quotation format, as most are working with an array, so it would be good to know which one you are actually using here.  In the future people working with postcodes.io may find this question and it might have value if the question is complete.